# How does windows determine "no internet access"?

Tags: windows, networking

I've seen this several times (mainly in VMs): although the machine is connected to the local network the OS (at the moment I am talking about Win 8.1 as guest in Virtualbox) notifies me:

> Network: No internet access

I just want to know **how** Windows draws that conclusion.

Comment: When it can't talk to a specific Microsoft site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [`article of SuperUser`](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/) blog talks to the  details how Windows does it.

Comment: I was just posting that.... :)