# How does Windows 10 determine it has access to Internet?

Tags: networking, windows-10

There is [a question about how Windows 7 checks for Internet connectivity](https://superuser.com/questions/728744/how-does-windows-determine-no-internet-access) (which leads to a [SU blog article](https://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/)).

I have a Windows 10 machine which currently displays

[image]

But:

- I do have internet access (browsing works fine)
- following the article I tried both checks mentioned there (resolution od an address and retrieval of a page, or resolution of another address to check the IP) and both are successful

**Is the check on Windows 10 different?**

Note: the connection is a straight one, without proxies (I mention this just in case as there were  discussions about proxies either blocking attempts, or requiring an authenticated connection)

Comment: Per https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4p6r9r/windows_10_captive_portal_detection/  "On my Windows 10 the URL is www.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt and ipv6.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt, and the site ipv6.msftncsi.com exists too. You may need to whitelist them all."

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose: thanks - I just checked and it is also available and the content reachable.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread your question. I believe the icon/status is sometimes just confused. :D

Comment: This might be caused by the anti-virus. Which anti-virus have you installed?

Comment: @harrymc: none on that machine, but it also happens with another one running TrendMicro.

Comment: There are reports that the indication may be temporarily wrong, but may fix itself with time.

Comment: I can confirm that the indicator gets 'stuck' sometimes thinking you have no connection when you do.  Most of the time, just reconnecting to the network seems to fix it, but sometimes it persists.

Comment: Does restarting the `Network Location Awareness` service get the icon's status working?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: I have been wandering with the laptop today (switching from wired to wireless) and now the status is back to correct. It will be wrong at some point though, so I will restart the service at that time. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If access is confirmed and your icon shows the yellow exclamation, then one of Microsoft's "phone home" sites is either blocked at the firewall, through your virus protection software, or any number of Windows 10 blocking software (O&O ShutUp10). Windows 10 determines internet access through this "feature". Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you mean the measures I mentioned (linked articles and checks)?